# Circular buffer increment using alternate method

Tags: c

[image: Circular buffer incrementation]
I am not able to understand how does the last statement increments the pointer.Can somebody explain me with few examples?

Comment: This is a really bad code.

Comment: Because of the power-of-two nature, it can make use of a bitmask (BUFFERSIZE-1) to roll the index back to zero when it overflows.  The author of the code apparently is trying to avoid the performance hit of using the modulo operator or a conditional branch.

Comment: shouldnt he directly AND it with [BUFFERSIZE-1] instead of ANDING it with (void *)[BUFFERSIZE-1]?

Comment: Please don't post images of text.

Answer (score 1):

The code, as shown:

```
aptr = (aptr + 1) & (void *)(BUFFERSIZE - 1);
    // |________| incremented here
```

Since it is a circular buffer AND the buffer size is a power of 2, then the `&` is an easy and fast way to roll over by simply masking.  Assuming that the `BUFFERSIZE` is `256`, then:

```
num & (256 - 1) == num % 256
num & (0x100 - 1) == num % 0x100
num & (0x0ff) == num % 0x100
```

When the number is not a power of 2, then you can't use the masking technique:

```
num & (257 - 1) != num % 257
num & (0x101 - 1) != num % 0x101
num & 0x100 != num % 0x101
```

The `(void *)` allows the compiler to choose an appropriate width for the `BUFFERSIZE` constant based on your pointer width... although it is generally best to know - and use! - the width before a statement like this.

I added the hex notation so to make more clear why the `&` results in an emulated rollover event.  Note that `0xff` is binary `0x11111111`, so the AND operation is simply masking off the upper bits.

Comment: My doubt is the num gets ANDED with (void *)(BUFFERSIZE-1),how come you can directly AND it with (256-1),since it it actually ANDING num with pointer type and not just plain integer. My assumption is, had it been num &(BUFFERSIZE-1),it would have yielded the final answer that you are talking about.

Comment: The `aptr` was likely declared as some type of pointer, i.e. `uint16_t* aptr`, in which case, this is valid.

Comment: Passing a pointer value to bitwise and is a [constraint violation](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.10p2) and so should produce diagnostics.

Comment: Agreed.  I'll leave my *incorrect* comment up for posterity.

Answer (score 1):

2 problems with this approach.

A) Using a pointer with a bit-wise operation is not portable code. [@Ilja Everilä](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46794911/circular-buffer-increment-using-alternate-method#comment80538051_46795142)

```
  char *aptr;
  // error: invalid operands to binary & (have 'char *' and 'void *')
  // The following increments the index:  (not really)
  // aptr = (aptr + 1) & (void *)(BUFFERSIZE-1);
```

B) With compilers that support the non-standard math on a `void *` akin to a `char *`, the math is wrong if `aptr` point to an object wider than `char` and `BUFFERSIZE` is the number of elements in the buffer and not the byte-size.  Of course this depends on how the non-standard complier implements `some_type * & void *`.  Why bother to unnecessarily code to use some implementation specific behavior?

---

Instead use `i % BUFFERSIZE`. This portable approach works when `BUFFERSIZE` is a power-of-2 and well  as when it is not. When a compiler sees `i % power-of-2` and `i` is some unsigned type, then the same code is certainly emitted as `i & (power-of-2 - 1)`.

For compilers that do not recognize this optimization, then one should consider a better compiler.

```
#define BUFFERSIZE 256
int main(void) {
  char buf[BUFFERSIZE];

  // pointer solution
  char *aptr = buf;
  aptr = &buf[(aptr - buf + 1) % BUFFERSIZE];

  // index solution
  size_t index = 0;
  index = (index + 1) % BUFFERSIZE;
}
```